# are JSLinks on WebPart , View , Fields mutually exclusive?

Tags: jslink, client-side-rendering

Elio Struyf already [blogged in 2013](http://www.eliostruyf.com/applying-js-link-on-task-lists-breaks-the-default-rendering-of-the-checkboxes/) about a problem with missing Microsoft CSR Templates when you add a JSLink on the **webpart**. The checkboxes (from `hierarchytaskslist.js`) do not display.

[image]

Seems that **NONE** of the VIEW JSLinks files execute when the WEBPART JSLink property has any value.

When the WEBPART JSLink is emptied, all **3** CSR Templates execute just fine:

[image]

### Now my questions are:

- Can a script tell if it was executed from a WebPart or View JSLink?

  - So I can present the iCSR developer with a warning about the conflict
- What do JSLink settings on Fields do?

  - Are they ignored because View/WebParts JSLinks take precedence?
  - Do they execute no matter what is defined in View/WebPart JSLinks?

*yes, I can add Fields JSLinks to the JSLink Manager and test myself.. but I have wasted enough time on this and want to put this JSLink Manager on GitHub*

## Update #1

JSLinkManager **Bookmarklet** (so works in all Browsers) is on GitHub: https://icsr.github.io/JSLinkManager.html

[image]

Comment: I've never run into conflicts between scripts loaded through a field and scripts loaded through a view.  Never heard of that problem with the webpart, though.  And you are using full URLs?  I thought JSLink had to use a token (~site or ~layouts, etc.)?

Comment: Yes full urls work fine, easy way of including CDN files like jQuery (*now I have to wash my mouth*).  ~sitecollection references have the same issue.. WebPart JSLink overrules the View JSLink (which totally explains why there is a problem with missing default CSR script behaviour). Once my *Apply-CSR-in-under-3-seconds-to-any environment* Bookmarklet works I'll -investigate JSLinks on Fields ⌚ PS... that LinkManager is [here](https://365csi.nl/bookmarklet.php?script=365toolkit_JSlink_add&name=JSLinkManager) ...  needs some work to make it public use for JavaScript nitwits, but it works